# Show next item in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring, nslog

I have an array that im using to display names however I wish to show both the current name selected and also the next name.

IE

If its player 1 go at a game then show

Player 1 take your go

Player 2 get ready to take your go

This is what i have so far this only displays the current string and loops until end of game.

```
    if (_index == _players.count) {
            _index = 0;
        }


        NSString * playerName = (NSString*)_players[_index++];
//        NSString * nextplayerName = (NSString*)_players[_index++];

        NSLog(@" player %@", playerName);

        self.turnlabel.text = playerName;
```

How can I display the next item in the array but still have the array continue in order as it is above?

Comment: have you tried `_index + 1 % _players.count`? (Index plus one mod array count)

Comment: How would i go about using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. You should not increment _index after getting the next player name, since you are not yet advancing to that player.

```
if (_index == _players.count) 
{
  _index = 0;
}
//Get the player at the current index
NSString * playerName = (NSString*)_players[_index];

//advance the index to the next play, and "wrap around" to 0 if we are at the end.
index = (index+1) %_players.count

//load the next player's name, but don't increment _index again.
NSString *nextplayerName = (NSString*)_players[_index];

NSLog(@" player %@. nextPlayer = %@", playerName, nextplayerName);

self.turnlabel.text = playerName;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. However its coming up with errors at two locations the % in         index = (index+1) % _players.count is giving error Invalid operands to binary. And also in nslog its not regognising nextplayersname. Any ideas?

Comment: index = (index+1) % _players.count; this line is the on giving me error

Comment: _index = (_index+1) % _players.count; fixed it needed a _ before index and ; at end sorry needed to rub my eyes a few times. :)

Comment: Bear in mind that when people post code in a forum, it's as a guide to what to do. You should not try and copy-paste it into your program directly. Rather, see what it does and adapt it to your needs. I made a few typos in my post. That shouldn't stop you.

Answer (score 0):

To loop over an NSArray you may want to use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` like:

```
[_players enumerateObjectsUsingBlock ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    NSString * playerName = (NSString*)_players[_index++];
    NSLog(@" player %@", playerName);
}];
```

See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock).

Comment: This will crash in the last iteration.